# Local conservation of zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

In a recent lecture, Prof. gave the following "imprecise" statement and encouraged us to take the time to make it precise and to prove it. My intuition is lacking, so I do not quite understand what the gist of the statement is/ could not put it in simpler words, and so I am struggling to make it precise. What I've written from the previous lecture is

> **Local Conservation:** If $g_t : U \to \mathbb{C}$, for $t \in I$, is a continuously varying family of (non-[illegible]) holomorphic functions, then $0$'s are locally conserved with multiplicity. Prove using the Argument Principle

I have additionally the qualification to this that, for compact $K \subseteq U$, $g_t |_K$ varies continuously in the uniform topology (topology of uniform convergence).

Specifically, what should be meant by "locally conserved?" Secondly, "varies continuously in the uniform topology" means that, over $t \in I$, specifically the version per se of continuity referenced is that of the uniform topology?

As far as involving the argument principle/ working towards a proof outline, since $g_t$ always being holomorphic suggests it has no poles over $U$, if $n(C,z)$ is the winding number of closed contour $C$ about a zero $z$ of $g_t$ (ie, at least one), the argument principle is simply that
$$\oint_C g_t'(z) / g_t(z) ~ dz = 2\pi i \sum_a n(C,a),$$

where $a$ is a zero of $g_t$ with multiplicity.

It is clear to me that showing that this integral is invariant in $t$ is productive, and I imagine this falls out of complete definitions readily, however we also need something which suggests that "nothing happens" to the placement of zeros so that the individual winding numbers do not change in $t$. Where would this come from?

Comment: I'm guessing that the illegible part is "non-zero", for the continuously-varying family $H_t(z) = tz^2$, where $t$ varies from $-1$ to $1$, has a moment ($t = 0$) where the algebraic count of zeroes goes off the charts. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint, but not a complete solution**

I suspect the general form of the proof is something like this:

1. The integral on the left is a continuous function of $t$ (under certain conditions, probably having to do with the choice of topology, and item 3 below). The C in the theorem is a simple closed curve surrounding one **or more** zeroes of $g_t$ (not a single zero, and not $f$...your transcription seems to have some problems).
2. The integral on the left takes values in a discrete set, hence it's constant (in areas where it's continuous)
3. As for "locally conserved", I'd say "if $g$ varies in such a way that $g_t$ is always nonzero on some (fixed) simple closed curve $C$ in $U$, the idea being that you don't want a zero to be able to creep outside your measurement curve during the variation process.